# PHP + HTML verifyng logged in users

Tags: php, html

so if coded some php and html but it doesn't seem to work

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHPRO Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php if( !isset( $_SESSION['id_usuario'] ) ): ?>
        <h2>Login Here</h2>
        <form action="login_submit.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    <label for="login_usuario">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="login_usuario" name="login_usuario" value="" maxlength="20" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="senha_usuario">Password</label>
                    <input type="text" id="senha_usuario" name="senha_usuario" value="" maxlength="20" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="? Login" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php else: ?>
        <h2>Logout Here</h2>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:81/clinica/logout.php">Log Out Link<p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

its a log in screen and i want logged in users to see the message "logout here", and the ones who have not yet logged in to see the normal log in page.

but it does not work, always displays the log in screen.

however, when using only php in a test page to see if the user is logged in, using this code, it works. --> `if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) = logged in`

```
<?php

/*** begin the session ***/
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario']))
{
    $message = 'You must be logged in to access this page';
}
else ........ rest of code
```

any help?

Comment: *doesn't seem to work* isn't much to go on. Hold on, let me get my OVE GLOVE.

Comment: In your first code example, do you have `session_start();` anywhere?

Comment: Your users are in a databse or similar? doesn't work is not obvious to me

Comment: I'm not sure why this post is closed... these moderators seem to be too quick to discredit a new person seeking coding help. I found this post extremely helpful in solving the same issue I was having. the code he listed is from an example tutorial that had the small error - the addition of `session_start()` fixed the problem - the original tutorial is: http://phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `session_start()` is added to the HTML document version. Without it, PHP will not know there is an active session. Thus, it thinks the user is not logged in every time you load the page.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHPRO Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php if( !isset( $_SESSION['id_usuario'] ) ): ?>
        <h2>Login Here</h2>
        <form action="login_submit.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    <label for="login_usuario">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="login_usuario" name="login_usuario" value="" maxlength="20" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="senha_usuario">Password</label>
                    <input type="text" id="senha_usuario" name="senha_usuario" value="" maxlength="20" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="? Login" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php else: ?>
        <h2>Logout Here</h2>
        <p><a href="http://localhost:81/clinica/logout.php">Log Out Link<p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfect. Also, sorry for not elaborating my question properly. Will do next time.

Comment: @esdo no problem. If this answered your question, please select it as the answer so others know you've been helped.